# "no suitable constructor found" Compilation error in case of varargs

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I continuously have the same error of

```
error: no suitable constructor found for FootballCriterionSet(String,FootballCriterion,FootballCriterion)
```

in case of constructor with varargs:

```
public FootballCriterionSet(String name, FootballCriterion... fc){}
```

the problem can be solved two ways:

1. Defining the constructor with exact number of parameters (1 + 2 in this case) which just calls the varargs constructor.
2. Stopping Play server, running "play clean-all" and running the server again (with waiting for compilation of all the classes).

Is there a way to solve/workaround the problem?

In particular I think that somehow forcing Play to do "clean-all" on each class change without stopping the server would work for me. Is it possible?

Comment: I think that doing a `clean-all` without stopping is not possible. Only option to run 2 instances, while the other is restarting.. but looks like overkill, just create 2 methods ;-)

Comment: The problem is that the number of arguments is really variable (this is why I use varargs ;).

Comment: So it works one time and then stops compiling?  What versions of Play & Scala are you using?

Comment: Hello James! Now I'm using play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_55) and the problem is still there.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the error occurs during compilation? If so, why not always compile using `play clean-all`? Also, how are you *not* stopping the server each time you recompile?